# Executing any git command closes the terminal window in Ubuntu

Tags: git

Executing any git command close the terminal window in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have latest version of git installed in my Ubuntu machine.

*git is already the newest version (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.5).*

When i execute any git command (ex git --version) from the terminal, it closes the terminal window.
I did remove & re-installation of the git package, but still I am seeing the same issue.
Is this ubuntu issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your terminal run in a mode when executables are run in similar way as `exec foo --bar ...` in a regular shell, i.o.w. the shell is exited before it runs the command.

Comment: exec git --version ==> prints as "git version 2.17.1" then terminal closed. What is the solution for this?

Comment: only git command is behaving like this. Other linux shell commands are working fine.

Comment: See your initialization scripts, aliases, etc... Shell usually doesn't do any dumb things like this.

Comment: I have checked my .bashrc file, there is one aliases added for git long back (to duplicate the git function for testing purpose). Removed that aliases from .bashrc file. Now it is working fine. Thanks for your support.